# Getting the URL by crawling whose content-type is not text/html

Tags: java, string, content-type

I can get all those url's whose content/type is text/html, but If I want those urls whose content/type is not text/html. Then how can we check that. As for the string we can use `contains` method, but it doesn't have anything like `notcontains`.. Any suggestions will be appreciated.. And also

```
The key variable contains:

Content-Type=[text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1]
```

This is the below code to check for text/html and I tried also for content-type that are not text/html but it also prints out those whose content-type are also text/html.

```
    try {
            URL url1 = new URL(url);
            System.out.println("URL:- " +url1);
            URLConnection connection = url1.openConnection();

            Map responseMap = connection.getHeaderFields();
            Iterator iterator = responseMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                String key = iterator.next().toString();

                if (key.contains("text/html") || key.contains("text/xhtml"))
                {
                    System.out.println(key);
                    // Content-Type=[text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1]
                    if (filters.matcher(key) != null){
                        System.out.println(url1);
                        try {
                            final File parentDir = new File("crawl_html");
                            parentDir.mkdir();
                            final String hash = MD5Util.md5Hex(url1.toString());
                            final String fileName = hash + ".txt";
                            final File file = new File(parentDir, fileName);
                            boolean success =file.createNewFile(); // Creates file crawl_html/abc.txt


                             System.out.println("hash:-"  + hash);

                                    System.out.println(file);
                            // Create file if it does not exist



                                // File did not exist and was created
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

                                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

                                // Also could be written as follows on one line
                                // Printwriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[0]));

                                            // Write text to file
                                Tika t = new Tika();
                                String content= t.parseToString(new URL(url1.toString()));


                                out.println("===============================================================");
                                out.println(url1);
                                out.println(key);
                                out.println(success);
                                out.println(content);

                                out.println("===============================================================");
                                out.close();
                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();



                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (TikaException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        // http://google.com
                    }
                }
  else if (!connection.getContentType().startsWith("text/html"))//print duplicate records of each url
                //else if (!key.contains("text/html"))
                {
                    if (filters.matcher(key) != null){
                     try {
                        final File parentDir = new File("crawl_media");
                        parentDir.mkdir();
                        final String hash = MD5Util.md5Hex(url1.toString());
                        final String fileName = hash + ".txt";
                        final File file = new File(parentDir, fileName);
                     // Create file if it does not exist
                        boolean success =file.createNewFile(); // Creates file crawl_html/abc.txt


                         System.out.println("hash:-"  + hash);

                         Tika t = new Tika();
                        String content_media= t.parseToString(new URL(url1.toString()));



                             // File did not exist and was created
                            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

                             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos);

                             // Also could be written as follows on one line
                             // Printwriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[0]));

                                         // Write text to file
                             out.println("===============================================================");
                             out.println(url1);
                             out.println(key);
                             out.println(success);
                             out.println(content_media);
                             //out.println("===============================================================");
                             out.close();
                             fos.flush();
                             fos.close();




                     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                         e.printStackTrace();
                     } catch (TikaException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    }

                }



            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        System.out.println("=============");
    }   
}
```

One method is to check individually for each content-type like for pdf it is application/pdf

```
if (key.contains("application/pdf")
```

and in the same way for xml... But any other method other than this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this help?

```
 if (!connection.getContentType.startsWith("text/html"))
```

Comment: this doesn't works..And it also takes the link whose content-type are text/html.. Any other idea.. And I also updated the question where text/html and non text/html are used..

Comment: Like this? If getContentType returns the "[" too, then strip it by using getContentType.substring(1)

Comment: this is working but it is printing duplicate records.. As for a particular url, there are many headers in a response so it is checking for each header, and if that header doesn't starts with `text/html` then it prints out that url.. So suppose if a particular url that is not text/html has 8 header in a response then it prints out that url 8 times.. Hope you understand what I am saying..

Comment: No, no, like in my post try accessing ContentType directly with getContentType - you don't need to iterate over all the headers then.

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with using:

```
if (key.contains("text/html") || key.contains("text/xhtml")) {
  //Do stuff
} else if (key.contains("application/pdf") {
  //Do other stuff
} else {
  //All other cases
}
```

Since the content type on other formats may vary from each type you probably need explicit cases for each content type. If a generic content type is encountered then the generic method (`else`) should be sufficient no? The [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) may be of use to you here.

My apologies if I misunderstood your issue. Can you provide an example printout of what the different values of `key` are through a test run? (10th line of your code)

Comment: thanks for replying back.. Problem is that I am not sure how many content-types are there, So in my case I need two things, One is all those urls whose content-type are text/html or text/xhtml and Second all those url's whose content-type are other than text/html or text/xhtml. So one way is to print out each urls and see the content-type and then add in if else loop for that content-type. But in future if somebody add any other pages of any other content-type then it is possible that I can miss that content-type. hope you understood now...

Comment: `key` contains values of the response header for a particular url. So each url has content-type so that's why I was checking for text/html.

Comment: In your case it would be best to implement solutions to any known content types you can and provide a warning to the user should it encounter an unknown content type. It would be impossible to write a system that works in 100% of the cases so your goal would be to prevent the system from having a critical error on the event of an unknown content type. Use the `else` case to catch unknown/unhandled content types and print a warning or give it a "best effort" method (probably using regular expressions) but be prepared for unexpected behaviors.